# Writing an upstart config file for Unicorn

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails, upstart, unicorn

I've had a good hunt and can't find a good example of an upstart script for Unicorn.

From what I've read however I think that upstart and unicorn might step on each others toes if I just try to set up a basic upstart config file given that unicorn manages its own workers etc...

Any tips or shortcuts before I dig in myself?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the init.d scripts that have been written for Unicorn. They should provide you with a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this config, but my personal choice is to use [BluePill](https://github.com/arya/bluepill) instead. It will give you more flexibility

```
description "Starts unicorn as the user 'rails'"
start on filesystem
chdir /apps/rails/sample_app
exec sudo -u deployer -i 'rvm ree; unicorn_rails -c /apps/rails/sample_app/config/unicorn.rb -E production' 
respawn
```